# Invalid Data returned for valid Address

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am trying to geocode the following address:

333111 Hwy 2, Suite A
Newport, WA 99156

For some reason, the geocoder's responds with two locations, one in Minnesota, and one *near* where the actual business is, but neither of them are correct.

The correct map location is displayed on the businesses website here:
http://www.a-1team.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=81&Itemid=194

I have tried removing the suite, changing the abbreviation etc, but I still cannot figure out how I should format this address to get it to geocode properly.

Is this a problem with the geocoder itself, or is it a problem with the way that I am formatting this specific address? (I have about 200 other addresses that get geocoded properly as part of the same process, so Im pretty sure Im submitting them properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a geocoder problem. I was going to suggest using [Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) to manually add this business (I've successfully done this in the past), but it looks like [Google already knows of it](https://plus.google.com/107057179660386465942/about) and can plot it at the [correct location](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=A-1+Team+Inc.,+U.S.+2,+Newport,+WA&hl=en&ll=48.175369,-117.063376&spn=0.002286,0.004576&sll=48.170751,-117.064819&sspn=0.018289,0.036607&oq=A-1+Team&hq=a-1+team+inc&hnear=U.S.+2&t=m&z=18&iwloc=A).

Maybe consider filing it as [a bug in the API](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/#Geocoding_API). It's what others seem to do.

Comment: Thanks, looked all over for *where* and *how* to file a bug with the geocoder, but everything pointed me here.

Answer (score 3):

When I use Google Maps to troubleshoot this, I too notice that typing in any form of the address you gave us was inaccurate. It would always take me near, but not exactly to the actual location.

However, when I examined the address Google Maps gave me, it stated that "Placement on map is approximate."

After that, I examined the website link you gave me, because surely they could not have it working, while we did not, right? Sure enough, when I examined the code for the embedded maps, here is what I find:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() { var yoomap1 = new YOOmaps('yoo-maps-1', 
{ lat:48.175156, lng:-117.063497...
```

Notice they give Latitude and Longitude coordinates.

IF you want to map this correctly, you can:

- Do what the website you linked did, and use "lat:48.175156, lng:-117.063497"
- Or, you could just use the address

> 1600 7th St, Newport, WA

While this address is not entirely accurate, it is very close to the actual address.

This could just possibly be a bug in Google Maps and its API. If anyone is more knowledgeable about this than me, please share.

Comment: The problem here is that I have a spreadsheet of businesses that get parsed and geocoded, which gets updated and reloaded frequently. I can manually adjust that particular business, and have done so for the live site (http://goingductless.com/consumer/how-to-go-ductless/find-an-installer), but I'll have to take that additional step every time I reload the spreadsheet.  Though the different address would geocode better, Im sure the business owner would complain about their address being "wrong". (I guess I could add another column to the spreadsheet for display address vs geocode address)